# In django, is aggregate(Count()) faster or better than .count() in anyway?

Tags: django

Django annotations is great for average, min/max, etc. It also does Count. So does that generate the same SQL as if I used the older .count() on the queryset?  Or does it generate more efficient SQL in some cases? Or worse SQL?

Sorry, to clarify, I meant to compare the count() operation against something like aggregate(Count('id')) where id is the PK of the table.

So with that, I believe Brian has the correct answer. In short, count() is simply a special case of aggregate().

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Calling the queryset's `.count()` method ultimately calls `Count()`.

Specifically: 
`django.db.models.QuerySet.count()` calls 
`django.db.models.sql.Query.get_count()`, which calls 
`django.db.models.sql.Query.add_count_column()`, which adds 
`django.db.models.sql.aggregates.Count` to the query.

The main difference between the two is that when you use `Count` directly, you specify the fields you want to count, whereas when you call `.count()` on the queryset, this will result in `SELECT COUNT(*)...` (except when you also use distinct() or when you limit the fields in the select clause, in which case it's more complicated).

Answer (score 13):

Apples and oranges. `.count()` does a SQL count on the current queryset. The `Count` aggregate, however, runs a count on relationships you specify on the queryset.

```
Pizza.objects.count() # Total amount of pizzas

Pizza.objects.aggregate(topping_count=Count('toppings')) # Total amount of toppings associated to a pizza

Pizza.objects.annotate(topping_count=Count('toppings')) # Total amount of toppings on each pizza
```

Comment: Assuming Pizza and Topping have a m2m relationship, calling aggregate on Pizza as in your second line will not return the total number of toppings for each pizza; it will outer join Pizza to Topping and basically count the number of joins. To get the number of toppings for each pizza you need to use annotate() instead of aggreate().

Comment: Sorry. I was off on my description of what's returned by aggregate. Updated the description and added `annotate` version to highlight the difference

Comment: If a topping is tied to more than one pizza, it will get joined to multiple pizzas in `Pizza.objects.aggregate(topping_count=Count('toppings'))` and thus this count will return more than the total number of toppings. To get the total number of toppings tied to a pizza (without duplicate counting), you'd probably want to do something like `Topping.objects.exclude(pizza_set=None).count()`.