# Django QuerySet Count() Returns NoneType

Tags: django

In views, I have the following snippet:

```
    try:
        count = MembershipPurchaseHistory.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count()
    except:
        count = 0
```

But somehow I got an error saying `count` has a `NoneType` value?
How is this possible?

Edit:
I wrote something like this:

```
if count > 0:
    # do something
```

Traceback Error:

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Edit 2:
Sorry. I found the error. It was referring to an installed lib, which compares a variable (which defaults to None) to an int. I omitted the variable and this happened.

Comment: Can you add full traceback?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Check the updated question.

Comment: This shouldn't be possible.  Please show us the whole code; perhaps the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnGordon @ neverwalkaloner Sorry. I found the error. It was referring to an installed lib, which compares a variable (which defaults to None) to an int. I omitted the variable and this happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count
count = MembershipPurchaseHistory.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).aggregate(Count('id'))['id__count']
```

You can try this method, this has better performance as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7958124/8283848)